# Keep a javascript variable after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new in javascript and jQuery. 
I'm using ajax calls to get data from my server. The fact is, I'm losing my javascript variables after the call .. 
Here is what I did : the variable is define outside any function and treat in an other function.

```
var a = 0;
function myfunction(url){
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        timeout: 20000,
        success: function(data){
                  // Do some stuff
                  // The a variable is now undefined
                },
        error: function(){
                  // Do some stuff
                }
       });
}
```

Everything is working fine, the only thing is that I need to keep my variables ... but it looks like it's gone ..

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Did you do it exactly like that, or did you in fact declare the variable inside another functions scope!

Comment: As the worst case you can use global variables.

Comment: This is variable scope in it's finest, my friend.

Comment: The 'a' variable is gone
Yes I did it this way, the variable is define outside functions

Comment: How can I change the variable scope?

Comment: Seems to work for me [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qNznR/) ??

Answer (score 3):

You say you're using your variable in another function (but don't show us that function). However, that function is probably running before your AJAX call is complete. This is what "asynchronous" means -- they don't take place at the same time.

To fix this, add some more code inside your `success` callback, where it will run only after the `a` variable is changed.

Comment: But I set the 'a' variable before doing the ajax call.. 
I add a console.log before the ajax call and in the success function. 
Before the call I've the right value of the variable and after, the variable is undefined ...
Is there a way to pass something in the settings of the ajax call?

Comment: You need to share some more code, so we can see exactly how you're using this variable throughout your code.

Comment: But in the other part of my code, I just increment the variable, nothing relevant ... just
 a++; or a--;

Comment: You were right, I add some console.log and it looks like function which initiate the variable is not done before the end of the ajax call. How can I wait for that?

Comment: You can't know exactly when the AJAX call will be done, but you can set a function to run only after that point by adding [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) after the `.ajax()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This works and the url does stay in scope.  What you should check is if you are getting an error - this will prevent success from running (toss an `alert("error");` or something similar in there to test).

I use Firebug in FireFox to help me out.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var a = 0;

function doSomething (url){
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            timeout: 20000,
            success: function(data){
                      alert(a);
                    },
            error: function(){
                      // Do some stuff
                    }
           });
    }

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="doSomething('variableScope.html'); return false;">Do it</a>
```

Comment: Then your question/code sample is incomplete - you can add a debugger; statement to your JavaScript block right after where you are trying to access the a variable - this might help give some insight.
If you're in a dynamic app, you should strongly type your variable as well since it might be getting overwritten by another function (strongly typed means to give it a more specific name to its function like pageLoadStatus, or someting like that.